# JSON-RPC строка в Java

Tags: java, c#, json, request, rpc

Граждане, прошу прощения, но даже не знаю как называется то, что я делаю (интересно также узнать кто меня поймет).
Есть примерно такой JSON запрос

```
{
  "id":0,
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "method":"server.filter.list",
  "params":{
    "locale":1033
  }
}
```

Коллега писал на C#, создал переменную для данного запроса:

```
string json = @"{""id"":""0"",""jsonrpc"": ""2.0"",""method"": ""server.filter.list"",""params"": {""locale"": 1033}}"`
```

Хочу корректно создать такую же переменную для передачи запроса в будущем, НО только на Java.

Собственно вопрос:

1. Как называется данный процесс?
2. Как мне писать на java его?

Буду очень благодарен. Если что-то неверно написал или оформил пишите сразу может смогу объяснить.

Вот так будет верно?

```
String json = "{\"id\":\"0\",\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",\"method\": \"server.filter.list\",\"params\": {\"locale\": 1033}}";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете точно так же "руками" собрать нужную строку в Java. Этот процесс называется "объявление строковой переменной":

```
String json = "{\"id\":0,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"server.filter.list\",\"params\":{\"locale\":1033}}";
```

Однако, обычно вам нужно подставлять какие-то значения, разбирать полученный ответ и работа со строками становится неудобной. Поэтому, на практике используют библиотеки - JSON-мэпперы.

Сначала создается класс(ы), описывающий структуру JSON-сообщения. Создается экземпляр такого объекта, заполняются поля. Затем средствами библиотеки преобразуют объект в JSON-строку. Это называют JSON-сериализацией. Обратный процесс (преобразование строки в объект) - JSON-десериализацией. Выглядит это для вашего случая примерно так:

```
private class Request {
    private Long id;
    private String jsonrpc;
    private String method;
    private Map<String, Object> params;

    // ... геттеры и сеттеры 
}

// получаем строку
Request request = new Request()
request.setId(0);
request.setJsonrpc("2.0");
request.setMethod("server.filter.list");
Map params = new HashMap();
params.put("locale", Integer.valueOf(1033));
request.setParams(params);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeToString(request);
```

Конкретная реализация последних двух строк зависит от библиотеки. Из наиболее популярных можно упомянуть:

- [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
- [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

---

Если присмотреться, ваш запрос похож на сообщение в протоколе [JSON-RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC). В таком случае лучше воспользоваться одной из [специализированных библиотекой для этого протокола](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/implementations#Java).

Comment: да, это и есть JSON-RPC.
Я уже в течении 4-5 часов мучаюсь и пишу простенький запрос)